# JMeter - Looping

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have the following script with 1 thread and 2 iterations.  [image]

[image]

Debug in Switch is not called. The second Google in the first iteration and the second Yahoo in the second iteration are not executed.  Why?
Thank you for the help.

I added the image of Switch Controller. 
[image]
Google and Yahoo are Simple Controllers with one HTTP Request Sampler.

Comment: Need more information about the switch value of your Switch Controller. And what is the element type of Google and Yahoo inside the Switch controller? Are they if controller?

Comment: Edi, I added what you've requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove spaces in the `Domains.csv` file in the second column. As of now `action= Google` is checked instead of `action=Google`. so the behaviour.

**Domains.csv**

```
domain_1,domain_2
Google,Google
Yahoo,Yahoo
```

Note: As you are using `Switch Controller`, it executes only matching element inside of it.

`Debug Sampler in Switch` element will never be matched as you are looking for either `Google` or `Yahoo`.

As `Edi Prayitno` mentioned, you can keep it inside the Simple Controller, if you want to execute `Debug Sampler in Switch` every time.

Comment: Thank you very much, Naveen. Great help. I did not know that the space after the coma is counted.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Based on the help of Switch Controller above, you put the Switch Value = ${action}. **It means you filled the Switch Value with the name of the subordinate element**. When ${action} name = Google, it will execute subordinate element = Google. When ${action} = Yahoo, it will execute subordinate element name = Yahoo.That means Debug in Switch will be never be called.

If you want to put debug step inside of Switch Controller, you can re-arrange your test as below:
[image]

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you Edi for explanation.